# What's the purpose of the syscall instruction?

Tags: assembly, system-calls

Or, in other words: what's the difference between `syscall` and `int <kernel-interrupt-number>`?

The only obvious reason that I can think of is that the interrupt number varies across operating systems, and having a new, unique instruction gives more consistency. However system calls numbers and arguments still varies across operating systems, so the gain in consistency is really low.

Probably intercepting interrupts requires more work for the kernel? (Hence there is a performance gain for using `syscall`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track; The motivation for the `syscall` instruction was mainly performance. You can read more about this [in AMD's "SYSCALL and SYSRET Instruction Specification"](http://support.amd.com/it/Embedded_TechDocs/21086.pdf).

Some excerpts from the documentation:

> To initiate a call to the operating system, an application
>   transfers control to the OS through gate descriptors (task,
>   interrupt, trap, or call gates). Control transfer is done by using
>   either a CALL instruction or a software interrupt. Setting up these control gates
>   (as well as the later return via a RET or IRET instruction) is
>   slowed down by the segmentation-related overhead. 
>   ....
>   SYSCALL and SYSRET are instructions used for low-latency
>   system calls and returns in operating systems with a flat
>   memory model and no segmentation. These instructions have
>   been optimized by reducing the number of checks and memory
>   references that are normally made so that a call or return takes
>   less than one-fourth the number of internal clock cycles when
>   compared to the current CALL/RET instruction method.